# MVC - correct place for view logic, childaction, partial view or seperate partial

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been reading numerous blogs and trying to determine what is the best approach both from a patterns and practices to performance.

**Option 1** 
I have a partial view Index.cshtml with the following..

```
@if (Model.SomeBooleanProperty)
{
     <div>A chunk of HTML</div>
}
```

**Option 2**
I have a partial view Index.cshtml with the following..

```
@Html.Partial("SomeBooleanProperty", Model)
```

and that partial view has the boolean logic.

```
@if (Model.SomeBooleanProperty)
{
     <div>A chunk of HTML</div>
}
```

**Option 3**
I have a partial view Index.cshtml with the following..

```
@Html.Action("AControllerMethod", "Controller", Model)
```

And AControllerMethod as follow

```
[ChildActionOnly]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post | HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult AControllerMethod(SomeModel model)
{
   if (model.SomeBooleanProperty)
   {
    return View(model);
   }
   else
   {
        return new ContentResult() { Content = String.Empty };
        //return null
   }
}
```

and then that partial returned would be like the following(no conditional logic)

```
<div>A chunk of HTML</div>
```

Option 3 seems best to me from a seperation of concerns point of view, as I am not having logic in the view, but then it also seems to me an anti pattern as surely it will impact performance as I have been reading blogs that say child actions impact performance.

Any help is appreciated.
J

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it depends on where else you will require the same output.

If you are going to re-use the display logic for that model in other parts of your site, it would make sense to have a partial view containing the if statement/markup, and then call `@Html.Partial("SomeBooleanProperty", Model)` wherever you need to display the partial view.

If for example you are only adding this logic on one page, just have the if statement/markup in the main view, as there is no need to separate it out.

I would not use option 3 for controlling display logic, as it is view logic there is no problem in having the conditional logic performed in the view.

Option 3 would simplify your view model, meaning you don't have to pass all the data required into the parent view, however there would be a performance overhead invoking the required controller.

Comment: Thanks Oliver, that makes sense to me. Cheers for your input.

Comment: +1 - I like option 2 unless there is a need for reuse (as you pointed out). It's worth noting that having the view invoke an action (option #3) requires the view to know (at least abstractly) about the controller, which bothers me (at least from a purist point of view). It introduces bidirectional relationships.